# function that access specific dataframe based on variable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, flask

I have a bunch of dataframes:

1. mike_df
2. bob_df
3. jim_df

etc...

I also have a function (utilizes flask_login) that captures the current user logged in (`flask_login.current_user.id`) , and want to display that users respective data.

The idea is, when the user logs in I can join their username with the string '_df' and propagate their data.

Code below for concreteness:

```
@app.route('/somepage')
def somepage():
     user = str(current_user.id) #this will return 'mike', or 'bob', or 'jim' depending on who is logged in.
     select_correct_df = user+'_df' #if mike logs in it should equate to 'mike_df' -- i'm aware this just outputs a string lol

     return render_template('page.html', df = select_correct_df )
```

The problem I'm having is, you cannot join a variable and a string and get a dataframe. So how do I pass a variable into the name of the dataframe?

Is this possible without putting all the dataframes into a dictionary?

Comment: is there a limited amount of dataframes? or do you have an arbitrary (large or modifying live) value of them? do you need to just read or also edit them?

Comment: lets assume large number of dfs, and no need to edit them

Comment: do you have some variables with the dataframes? or do you have a bunch of csv files in a folder? where do they come from?

Comment: they are loaded via a csv file, but eventually will come straight out of snowflake.

Comment: I'm very curious as to why you don't want to put the dfs into a dictionary? You want to use a string to get a certain value, that is precisely what dictionaries are made to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey, so if you are reading them from the csv file you have two options:

1. Preload them and store them in a dict:

import pandas as pd

```
DFS = {}
PATH_TO_CSVS = "my/path/to/csvs/"
for name in "john_df", "maria_df", "mike_df":
     DFS[name] = pd.read_csv(PATH_TO_CSVS + name + ".csv")

@app.route('/somepage')
def somepage():
     user = str(current_user.id) #this will return 'mike', or 'bob', or 'jim' depending on who is logged in.
     select_correct_df = user+'_df' #if mike logs in it should equate to 'mike_df' -- i'm aware this just outputs a string lol

     return render_template('page.html', df = DFS[select_correct_df])
```

2. Load them when requested.

import pandas as pd

```
PATH_TO_CSVS = "my/path/to/csvs/"

@app.route('/somepage')
def somepage():
     user = str(current_user.id) #this will return 'mike', or 'bob', or 'jim' depending on who is logged in.
     select_correct_df = user+'_df' #if mike logs in it should equate to 'mike_df' -- i'm aware this just outputs a string lol

     return render_template('page.html', df = pd.read_csv(PATH_TO_CSVS + user + ".csv"))
```

Comment: OP asks if dict can be avoided?

Answer (score 2):

Addition to @miquelvir:

If you really want to avoid dicts (as asked in the comments) and also do not want to load the csv on call, you can Multi-Index the pandas.DataFrame (more complex but maybe usefull if you need to do some data engineering)

```
    mike_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
        "B": ["B0", "B1", "B2", "B3"],
        "C": ["C0", "C1", "C2", "C3"],
    },
    index=[0, 1, 2, 3],
)
bob_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["A4", "A5", "A6", "A7"],
        "B": ["B4", "B5", "B6", "B7"],
    },
    index=[4, 5, 6, 7],
)
    data_df = pd.concat([mike_df, bob_df], keys=["mike", "bob"])  # or mike_df, etc..
```

yielding:

```
         A   B    C
mike 0  A0  B0   C0
     1  A1  B1   C1
     2  A2  B2   C2
     3  A3  B3   C3
bob  4  A4  B4  NaN
     5  A5  B5  NaN
     6  A6  B6  NaN
     7  A7  B7  NaN
```

retrieving data:

```
mikes_data = data_df.loc['mike'].dropna(axis=1)
    A   B   C
0  A0  B0  C0
1  A1  B1  C1
2  A2  B2  C2
3  A3  B3  C3
```

you can add more data like:

```
# also possible in a loop to load data
jim_df = jim_df.set_index([["jim"]*len(jim_df.index), jim_df.index])
data_df = data_df.append(jim_df)

# retrieving
jims_data = data_df.loc['jim'].dropna(axis=1)
```

---

Edit 8.4.2021:

```
jim_df["jim"] = "jim"  # maybe an unnecessary detour, but what I know that works
jim_df = jim_df.set_index(["jim", jim_df.index])
```

to:

```
jim_df = jim_df.set_index([["jim"]*len(jim_df.index), jim_df.index])
```

Comment: very interesting, i like this approach